# Half space after initial in citation with biblatex-apa

Tags: spacing, biblatex

I am using biblatex-apa, and have two authors with the same last name. When I do the in-text citation, their first initial is printed before the name. It looks like there is a full space after the initial and before the last name. How do I instead make it a half space?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{williams1980,
    title = {Predication},
    volume = {11},
    timestamp = {2017-06-05T20:27:26Z},
    eprinttype = {jstor},
    eprint = {4178153},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Linguistic inquiry},
    author = {Williams, Edwin},
    date = {1980},
    pages = {203--238}
}
@inproceedings{williams2012,
    title = {Null Complement Anaphors as Definite Descriptions},
    volume = {22},
    url =     {http://journals.linguisticsociety.org/proceedings/index.php/SALT/article/view/2646},
    timestamp = {2017-06-05T20:27:31Z},
    booktitle = {Semantics and {{Linguistic Theory}}},
    author = {Williams, Alexander},
    urldate = {2016-02-01},
    date = {2012},
    pages = {125--145}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \textcite{williams2012} or \textcite{williams1980}

    A.\,Williams (2012) or E.\,Williams (1980)

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: williams]

The `\textcite{williams2012}` has a bigger space than `A.\,Williams (2012)`. How do I make the `\textcite` produce the half space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibnamedelimi}{\addnbthinspace}
```

Is a promising start, but because `biblatex` does not automatically use `\bibnamedelimi` after the given name if it is in initials, we have to do that ourselves. For `biblatex-apa` this comes down to

```
\newbibmacro*{name:giveni-family}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimi}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
    \ifprefchar
      {}
      {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
  \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}

\renewbibmacro*{labelname:doname}[8]{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{>}{1}}
              or
              test {\ifuniqueprimaryauthor}}
    {\setcounter{uniquename}{0}}
    {}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:family}{#1}{#3}{#5}{\relax}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family}{#1}{#3}{\relax}{\relax}}%
  \or
     \ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:giveni-family}{#1}{#4}{#5}{\relax}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:giveni-family}{#1}{#4}{\relax}{\relax}}%
  \or
     \ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#3}{#5}{\relax}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#3}{\relax}{\relax}}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

We define a new name macro `name:giveni-family` that is a copy of `biblatex.def`'s `name:given-family`, but instead of printing `\bibnamedelimd` after the given name, it prints `\bibnamedelimi`. We use this macro when we redefine `apa.cbx`'s `labelname:doname` to call `name:giveni-family` instead of `name:given-family` in the 1 branch of `\ifcase\value{uniquename}%`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{williams1980,
    title = {Predication},
    volume = {11},
    timestamp = {2017-06-05T20:27:26Z},
    eprinttype = {jstor},
    eprint = {4178153},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Linguistic inquiry},
    author = {Williams, Edwin},
    date = {1980},
    pages = {203--238}
}
@inproceedings{williams2012,
    title = {Null Complement Anaphors as Definite Descriptions},
    volume = {22},
    url =     {http://journals.linguisticsociety.org/proceedings/index.php/SALT/article/view/2646},
    timestamp = {2017-06-05T20:27:31Z},
    booktitle = {Semantics and {{Linguistic Theory}}},
    author = {Williams, Alexander},
    urldate = {2016-02-01},
    date = {2012},
    pages = {125--145}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewrobustcmd*{\bibnamedelimi}{\addnbthinspace}

\newbibmacro*{name:giveni-family}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimi}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
    \ifprefchar
      {}
      {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
  \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}

\renewbibmacro*{labelname:doname}[8]{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{>}{1}}
              or
              test {\ifuniqueprimaryauthor}}
    {\setcounter{uniquename}{0}}
    {}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:family}{#1}{#3}{#5}{\relax}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family}{#1}{#3}{\relax}{\relax}}%
  \or
     \ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:giveni-family}{#1}{#4}{#5}{\relax}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:giveni-family}{#1}{#4}{\relax}{\relax}}%
  \or
     \ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#3}{#5}{\relax}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#3}{\relax}{\relax}}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{williams2012} or \textcite{williams1980}

  A.\,Williams (2012) or E.\,Williams (1980)
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]